# wxPython: call a wxApp from another wxApp

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to run a wxApp from another wxApp?
I am trying to simply call a program I wrote (called DataDeck) from a method of another wxApp, like it was a plugin.

something like:

```
def on_datadeck_btn_click(self, event):
        import datadeck.main
        datadeck.main.run()
        event.Skip()
```

where datadeck.main.run() is a classic start of a wxApp:

```
def run():
    app = DataDeck(0)
    app.SetAppName("DataDeck")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Right now, it correctly opens DataDeck the first time and it works, but it won't reopen DataDeck a second time after I close it. This would freeze everything.

**Update**: based on [@Mike Driscoll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014752/wxpython-call-a-wxapp-from-another-wxapp/8038430#8038430) answer, I documented myself more and came to the following solution:

I added an "entry point" in datadeck

```
def run_as_plugin():
    #[do some stuff related to XRC layouts and sysout redirection]
    MainGUI = datadeck.gui.maingui.MainGUI()
```

Where the constructor of MainGUI() automatically shows the wxFrame. Now my application behaves like it was a component of the caller wxApp.
Therefore, I modify the application method as follows:

```
def on_datadeck_btn_click(self, event):
    import datadeck.main
    datadeck.main.run_as_plugin()
    event.Skip()
```

**It was very simple**, indeed! I just had to modify my objects that deal with stdout redirection (not part of this question, I omit the details), and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should only be on wx.App. From what I've read online, you can't have two wx.App objects running in one script. You could probably do it using the subprocess module to open a new process though. Take a look at Editra to see some examples for how to do plugins. It is included with wxPython or you can download it separately.

Comment: You are right, even if you don't directly suggest me how to implement the solution, you pointed me to the right direction: avoid calling methods of datadeck responsible to creating the wx.App. See my question for an update. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Driscoll, Mike, If it can not be done, then what my code is doing? I'm sorry I miss something here.

Comment: @joaquin - I asked Robin Dunn to comment on your answer to explain why that isn't a good idea since I wasn't sure how to answer you myself. I hope his comment clarified the issue.

Comment: @Mike Driscoll. It is my honor to take private lessons from wxpython gurus as Robin Dunn and Mike Driscoll. Thanks for your work.

Comment: @joaquin You seem to be coming along quite well in your wxPython knowledge too.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly feasible. Not sure why it doesnt work for you.
This example works perfectly:

--main.py--

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title='Main', size=(353,270))
        button= wx.Button(self, -1, 'call app', pos=(10,10), size=(-1,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.capp, button)

    def capp(self, event):
        import datadeck
        datadeck.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

--datadeck.py--

```
import wx

class DDFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title='DDFrame', size=(353,270))
        button = wx.Button(self, -1, 'print something', pos=(100,100), size=(-1,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.say_hello, button)

    def say_hello(self, event):
        print 'something'

class DataDeck(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = DDFrame(None)
        frame.Show()
        return True

def run():
    app = DataDeck(1)
    app.SetAppName("DataDeck")
    app.MainLoop()
```

if you press the 'call app' button you get the new frame open. And you can open as many as you want.
Created aplications/frames are independent of each other. You can close any of them without affecting the others. And the system doesnt freeze.

Comment: +1 because you are almost right with this example. But I will accept the other answer since a) the wxPython community seems to agree with this b) I managed to get it working without creating a new wxApp in datadeck just for the case of invocation from another wxApp

Comment: almost right ? You asked how to call a wxApp from another wxApp and I showed you how to do it. The other answer says it can not be done... And you vote the other. Really curious...

Comment: Well, your example works, I have to admit it. But it does not work in my case. Maybe because datadeck is not a trivial application, neither is the application I am trying to enhance by calling datadeck. I don't really know. Nothing personal, I gave you a +1 because of this strange situation. The idea of avoiding having two wx.App in the same process gave by Mike Driscoll brought me to the answer. Thank you very much for your example, anyway!

Comment: Ok, this pluging thing is the common method to instantiate a wxpython class called from another class. The minor point is that that was not your question. whatever, dont mind.

Comment: I will try to be more clear in the next questions. I am sure that the SO community will upvote your answer if it agrees with yours :)

Comment: At best the behavior of having more than one wx.App at a time is "undefined" and platform dependent.  In practice it is likely to be fragile and likely to crash or rip a hole in space-time.  The main reason for this is that the native UI library is initialized as part of creating the wx.App object, as well as a lot of initialization-like actions in the runtime environment for wx and wx objects.  Some of these should only be done once.  The wx stuff we can deal with, but the platform libs and etc. is not so easy.